Fix for Apache Solr 9.7.0 Windows Start-up Issues
Problem
When trying to start Apache Solr 9.7.0 on Windows using either basic start command or cloud example, you might encounter these errors:

With basic start (.\solr.cmd start):

Failed to parse command-line arguments due to: Unrecognized option: --max-wait-secs
ERROR: Solr did not start or was not reachable.


With cloud example (.\solr.cmd start -e cloud):

Invalid command-line option: --cloud

Environment

Apache Solr: 9.7.0
OS: Windows 11
Java: JDK 17
Shell: PowerShell (as Administrator)


And yet another solr startup bug on Windows... Are there no tests ran on Windows before release ?

Root Cause
The Windows binary script (solr.cmd) contains inconsistent command switches that don't match what the parser expects. This appears to be a maintenance issue with the Windows scripts in Solr 9.7.0.
Solution

Navigate to your Solr installation directory
Create a backup of bin\solr.cmd
Open bin\solr.cmd in a text editor (like Notepad++ or VS Code)
Make these changes:

Find --max-wait-secs and replace with -maxWaitSecs
Find -cloud and replace with --cloud



Important Notes:

Only change one occurrence of each parameter
Don't use "Replace All" as it might affect other correct instances
Make sure you have backup before editing

After Fix
After applying these fixes, you might see these warnings which can be safely ignored:
WARNING: URLs provided to this tool needn't include Solr's context-root (e.g. "/solr"). 
Such URLs are deprecated and support for them will be removed in a future release. 
Correcting from [http://localhost:8983/solr] to [http://localhost:8983/].

WARNING: A command line option has enabled the Security Manager
WARNING: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Verification
After applying the fixes, verify that these commands work:
.\solr.cmd start          # Basic start
.\solr.cmd start -e cloud # Cloud example
.\solr.cmd status         # Status check

Additional Notes

These fixes are needed even when running PowerShell as Administrator
The JVM warning about large page memory can be ignored:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: JVM cannot use large page memory because it does not have enough privilege to lock pages in memory.


This appears to be a Windows-specific issue and doesn't affect Linux/Unix installations

References

Solr Control Script Reference
Getting Started Tutorial

